# Default time in kendo datetime picker

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, datetimepicker

As we know that we set the default start day of the week for calendar in kendo date time picker, is there any way we can set the default time in kendo date time picker?

If we use

value: new Date()

this will set the field with current date and time, but what I want is that, only the time picker in datetime picker should be defaulted to 9:00 AM which is by default 12:00 AM.

Comment: Although you see Time Picker value as `time` internally is stored as a JavaScript Date, so you might ignore the `date` but it will be there no matter what you do.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for default time without setting the value?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this??If so can you post ur answer?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this example](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datetimepicker/index.html).

Seems to me like they are specifying a default date using the constructor:

```
            $("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
                value:new Date()
            });
```

Comment: I have changed the reqmt little. Please provide me a solution if you have any..

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Use this article : http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datetimepicker

```
         var dateTimePicker = $("#dateTimePicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
          // set the selected value on the dateTimePicker to January 1st, 2011
          dateTimePicker.value(new Date(2011, 0, 1));

    var dateTimePicker = $("#dateTimePicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
    dateTimePicker.value("2/23/2000 10:00 AM");
```

Comment: I have changed the reqmt little. Please provide me a solution if you have any..

Thanx

Comment: var dateTimePicker = $("#dateTimePicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
    dateTimePicker.value("2/23/2000 9:00 AM"); 
     try this it will work

Comment: I don want a default date in the field, only the time has to be set to 9:00 AM when we click on time picker.

Thnx